# Running out of memory always on the same line

Tags: php, performance, memory, optimization, joomla

First of all, I am not looking for an answer saying "Check your PHP memory limit" or "You need to add more memory" or these kind of stuff ... I am on a dedicated machine, with 8GB of RAMS; 512MB of it is the memory limit. I always get an out of memory error on one single line :

To clarify: This part of the code belongs to [Joomla!](http://joomla.org) CMS.

```
function get($id, $group, $checkTime){
    $data = false;
    $path = $this->_getFilePath($id, $group);
    $this->_setExpire($id, $group);
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        if($data) {
            // Remove the initial die() statement
            $data   = preg_replace('/^.*\n/', '', $data); // Out of memory here
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is a part of Joomla's caching ... This function read the cache file and remove the first line which block direct access to the files and return the rest of the data.

As you can see the line uses a preg_replace to remove the first line in the cache file which is always :

```
<?php die("Access Denied"); ?>
```

My question is, **it seems to me as a simple process (removing the first line from the file content) could it consume a lot of memory if the initial $data is huge?** if so, what's the best way to work around that issue? I don't mind having the cache files without that die() line I can take of security and block direct access to the cache files.

Am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

As suggested by posts, regex seems to create more problems than solving them. I've tried:

```
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
```

after the regex then tried the same statement using `substr()`. The difference is very slight in memory usage. Almost nothing.

That's for your contributions, I am still trying to find out why this happen.

Comment: Why would you use a regexp to remove the first line from a file? "Now you have two problems."

Comment: I think your regexp is replacing ALL lines into nothing. Eventually using up all memory.

Comment: @Wooble I added a clarification that this code belongs to Joomla!

Comment: @nl-x No it just remove the first line. I dumped $data before and after and it didn't change anything else.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy how could you have dumped before and after while you get out of memory during the regexp? Im no regexp expert, but I think your expression states from the beginning of a line (^) until a newline (\n). And if you don't specify the count parameter, it will change all occurrences.

Comment: @nl-x I don't get out of memory all the time. Just when the website is heavily crawled. I am no regexp either but when I dump the data it just remove the first line :)

Answer (score 5):

Use substr to avoid the memory hungry `preg_replace()` , like this:

```
$data = substr($data, strpos($data, '?>') + 3);
```

As a general advice don't use regular expressions if you can do the same task by using other string/array functions, regular expression functions are slower and consume more memory than the core string/array functions.

This is explicitly warned in PHP docs too, see some examples:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-notes
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#refsect1-function.preg-split-notes

Comment: Now I know that `preg_replace()` is a memory hog. I will test and come again with the results. Thanks

Comment: I used `memory_get_usage()` to compare the memory usage between `substr` and `preg_replace()` and found that the difference is very very slight. I've updated the question; thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

don't use a string function to replace something in a huge string. You can cycle through the lines of a file and just break after you have found what your looking for.
check the PHP docs here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

basically what @cbuckley just said :p

Comment: I just realized I kind of gave the same answer that you did, before reading yours well enough. Your (and my) answer is NOT basically the same as cbuckley's answer, as our answer doesn't involve reading in the entire file at once. Cbuckley's answer does read the entire file at once (and splits it up into an array).

Answer (score 1):

If You just want to remove the first line of a file and return the rest, you should make use of [`file`](http://php.net/file):

```
$lines = file($path);
array_shift($lines);
$data = implode("\n", $lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using `file_get_contents()` that gets the entire file at once, which can be too big to run regexps on, you should use `fopen()` in combination with `fgets()` (http://php.net/fgets). This function gets the file line by line.

You can then choose to do a regexp on a specific line. Or in your case just skip the entire line.

So in stead of:

```
$data = file_get_contents($path);
if($data) {
    // Remove the initial die() statement
    $data   = preg_replace('/^.*\n/', '', $data); // Out of memory here
}
```

try this:

```
$fileHandler = fopen($path,'r');
$lineNumber = 0;
while (($line = fgets($fileHandler)) !== false) {
    if($lineNumber++ != 0) { // Skip the initial die() statement
        $data .= $line; // or maybe echo out $line directly so $data doesn't take up too much memory as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that, thank you. I think `$lineNumber++` is missing a `;` :)

Comment: Doh! You are right, sorry. But please don't call the handler FileLocation, as it doesn't try to tell you where the file is. But it is a pointer telling you where you are within the file. Hope this is clear to you. The pointer starts at the beginning of the file. And each time you call fgets() the pointer is moved to the next newline and returns everything in between. (BTW. I moved the lineNumber++ inside the if() )

Comment: Memory consumption with this one is higher that `preg_replace`

Comment: @AhmadAlfy as I commented in the last line, in stead of doing `$data .= $line;` you can also directly output the data. This avoids putting the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this in the file including the cached files:

```
define('INCLUDESALLOW', 1);
```

and in the file that will be included:

```
if( !defined('INCLUDESALLOW') ) die("Access Denied");
```

Then just use `include` instead of `file_get_contents`. This would run PHP code in the included though, not 100% sure if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There times that you will use more memory than the 8 MB php has allotted. If your unable to use less memory by making your code more efficient, you might have to increase your available memory. This can be done in two ways.

The limit can be set to a global default in php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 32M
```

Or you can override it in your script like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
...
```

For more on PHP memory limit you can see [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620602/php-memory-limit) or [ini.memory-limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: The very first sentence of the question: "First of all, I am not looking for an answer saying "Check your PHP memory limit" or "You need to add more memory" or these kind of stuff ... "